# How to Generate html issues report in SonarQube 5.1

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

We have recently upgraded SonarQube to 5.1 version. In earlier versions there was Issues report plugin to generate html report for the issues. Now that plugin becomes native in 5.1, I wonder where the settings for issues report is? Is there anyway to generate html issues report as earlier?

Answer (score 2):

To complement Alexandre's answer; The parameters are described [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Issues+Report+Plugin).

Since SonarQube 4.0 you can do the following:

```
sonar-runner -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true
```

Comment: I was not able to comment yet I wanted to contribute. BTW, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: In hind sight, I can probably edit this so that it would be more suitable as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are the same than before when the Issues Report was a Plugin.
See : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Getting+Issues+Report+in+Preview+Mode

Comment: this page does not exist anymore

Comment: The page seems to have moved to http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Issues+Report+Plugin